# Get FOREIGN KEY constraint failed when try to save, but same code works on shell

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I'm getting this error `FOREIGN KEY constraint failed` when trying to save some records to database, but similar code works fine when manually run in the shell. My code below:

**Models.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from sde.models import Invtypes
from corp.models import EveCharacter

class Cart(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    item = models.ForeignKey(Invtypes,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1,blank=False,null=False)
    price = models.IntegerField(default=0,blank=True,null=True)
    checkout = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    createdate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,blank=True)

    @property
    def get_total_price(self):
        return self.price * self.quantity

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s x %s' % (self.item,self.quantity)

class Order(models.Model):
    uid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4,help_text="UID")
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    receiver = models.ForeignKey(EveCharacter,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    totalprice = models.IntegerField(default=0,blank=False,null=False)

    ORDER_STATUS = (
        ('o','on hold'),
        ('f','finished'),
        ('c','canceled'),
        ('e','exception'),
    )

    status = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=ORDER_STATUS, blank=True, default='o')

    createdate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,blank=True)
    finishdate = models.DateTimeField(blank=True,null=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["createdate"]

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('order-detail', args=[str(self.uid)])

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s (%s-%s)' % (self.receiver,self.status,self.uid)

class OrderUnit(models.Model):
    uid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    order = models.ForeignKey('Order',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    item = models.ForeignKey(Invtypes,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0,blank=False,null=False,help_text="product amount")
    price = models.IntegerField(default=0,blank=False,null=False)

    ITEM_STATUS = (
        ('w','Waiting for processing'),
        ('s','Sent'),
        ('p','Partially Sent'),
        ('e','Out of stock'),
    )
    status = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=ITEM_STATUS, blank=True, default='w')

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s x %s (%s-%s)' % (self.item,self.quantity,self.status,self.uid)
```

**Views.py**

```
@login_required
def create_order(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        cartlist = request.POST.getlist('cart') #Get a list of submitted items
        character = EveCharacter.objects.get(name=request.POST.get('character')) #Get recipient
        order = Order(receiver=character,user=request.user) #Create Order
        totalprice = 0
        for cart in cartlist:
            r_cart = Cart.objects.get(pk=cart)
            temp = OrderUnit(order=order,item=r_cart.item,quantity=r_cart.quantity,price=r_cart.price) #These all have the correct values
            temp.save() #Get FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
            r_cart.checkout = True
            r_cart.save()
            totalprice += temp.price
        order.totalprice = totalprice
        order.save() #Order can be saved without error

    return render(request,'order/submit_order.html')
```

And traceback

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/order/create/

Django Version: 3.0.5
Python Version: 3.8.2
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'sde.apps.SdeConfig',
 'corp.apps.CorpConfig',
 'cart.apps.CartConfig',
 'order.apps.OrderConfig',
 'mptt']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\neoha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\neoha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 396, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

The above exception (FOREIGN KEY constraint failed) was the direct cause of the following exception:
  File "C:\Users\neoha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\neoha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\neoha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\neoha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py", line 21, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Work\django_test\evebackend2\order\views.py", line 25, in create_order
    temp.save()
  File "C:\Users\neoha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 745, in save
    self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert,
  File "C:\Users\neoha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 782, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(
  File "C:\Users\neoha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 887, in _save_table
    results = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, returning_fields, raw)
  File "C:\Users\neoha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 924, in _do_insert
    return manager._insert(
  File "C:\Users\neoha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\neoha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1204, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)
  File "C:\Users\neoha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1391, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\neoha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 100, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\neoha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "C:\Users\neoha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\Users\neoha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\neoha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\neoha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\neoha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 396, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

Exception Type: IntegrityError at /order/create/
Exception Value: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you trying to save OrderUnit that has foreign key to Order before saving Order. You created python object Order but didn't send it to database. Call order.save() before temp.save(), before your loop